# Using a case class to rename split columns with Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, split, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am splitting 'split_column' to another five columns as per the following code. However I wanted to have this new columns to be renamed so that they would have some meaningful names(let's say new_renamed1", "new_renamed2", "new_renamed3", "new_renamed4", "new_renamed5" in this example)

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("new_column", split(col("split_column"), "\\|")).select(col("*") +: (0 until 5).map(i => col("new_column").getItem(i).as(s"newcol$i")): _*).drop("split_column","new_column")

val new_columns_renamed = Seq("....., "new_renamed1", "new_renamed2", "new_renamed3", "new_renamed4", "new_renamed5") 

val df2 = df1.toDF(new_columns_renamed: _*)
```

However issue with this approach is some of my splits might have more than fifty new rows. In thi renaming  approach, a little typo (like extra comma, missing double quotes) would be painful to detect.

Is there a way to rename columns with  case class like below ?

```
case class SplittedRecord (new_renamed1: String, new_renamed2: String, new_renamed3: String, new_renamed4: String, new_renamed5: String)
```

Please note that in the actual scenario names would not look like new_renamed1, new_renamed2, ......, new_renamed5 , they would be totally different.

Comment: What's the mapping of the fields after `split` to their names in a case class? Is this by position?

Comment: There is no mapping between names and position.

Comment: How are you going to know what position maps to its name? There has to be _some_ mapping.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski mapping is complex in the real world scenario that's why answered there is no mapping between names and position. However in this example it is safe to assume position maps to name. Sorry about the confusing answer.

Comment: Didn't you write _"Here you have assumed that ith column take the name new_column(i) and it's not the actual case."_ under the accepted answer? I _am_ confused.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val names = Encoders.product[SplittedRecord].schema.fieldNames

names.zipWithIndex
  .foldLeft(df.withColumn("new_column", split(col("split_column"), "\\|")))
  { case (df, (c, i)) => df.withColumn(c, $"new_column"(i)) }
```

Comment: Good to know your approach, however my intention is to use a case class to rename the split columns. Here you have assumed that ith column take the name new_column(i) and it's not the actual case. The names would have a contextual meaning.

Comment: user9613318 has used the case class you have mentioned.

Comment: It's my bad this is indeed a valid answer even though I did not realize it. Thanks Ramesh for pointing it out. Accepted your answer.

Comment: @RobertKnox , its not my answer ;) its user9613318 who answered it ;)

Comment: Ramesh assumed the context of Answer when referring 'your'  and of course it's ambiguous :)

Comment: this is beautiful: Encoders.product[SplittedRecord].schema.fieldNames

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to *use the case class*

```
case class SplittedRecord (new_renamed1: String, new_renamed2: String, new_renamed3: String, new_renamed4: String, new_renamed5: String)
```

is through `udf` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def splitUdf = udf((array: Seq[String])=> SplittedRecord(array(0), array(1), array(2), array(3), array(4)))

df.withColumn("test", splitUdf(split(col("split_column"), "\\|"))).drop("split_column")
    .select(col("*"), col("test.*")).drop("test")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for !

Comment: Why `udf`?! Try to stay away from it as long as you can due to performance reasons.

Comment: Yeah I know @JacekLaskowski thanks for pointing that out again. Its just a possibility though

Comment: @RameshMaharjan You're too good at proposing alternatives that should not really be alternatives :)

Comment: Actually I couldn't think of otherwise at the moment @JacekLaskowski thats the main reason